# Laravel - Form validation - array one minimum 1 field required

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a form array like so:

```
<textarea name="intro[en]"></textarea>
<textarea name="intro[fr]"></textarea>
<textarea name="intro[de]"></textarea>
```

I have validation rules like the below:

```
public function rules()
{
        return [ 
            'intro.*' => 'required'
        ];
}
```

What I would actually need is that at least one of the intro s are filled in.

Is that possible with existing validators? If so what's the syntax? If not, how would I go about creating that validator?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is [`required_without_all`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-without-all):

```
'intro.en' => 'required_without_all: intro.fr, intro.de',
'intro.fr' => 'required_without_all: intro.en, intro.de',
'intro.de' => 'required_without_all: intro.en, intro.fr',
```

Comment: thank you :)
is there a better way to make it more dynamic ?
in case I will add a new language ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also

```
'intro' => 'required|array|min:1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
public function rules()
{
 return [
   'intro.*.en' => 'required',
   'intro.*.fr' => 'required',
   'intro.*.de' => 'required',
 ];
}
```

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom rule for it inside **AppServiceProvide** like below code

```
$this->app['validator']->extend('emptyArray', function ($attribute, $values, $parameters)
    {
        foreach($values as $data){
            if(count($data)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    Validator::replacer('emptyArray', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
    return 'You need to fill up at least one field for '.$attribute;
```

it will check whether the array field is empty or not.